# ArcGIS Pro - Basemap in 3D scene is wrong resolution

Tags: arcgis-pro, basemap

I recently started playing around with ArcGIS Pro again and I've noticed that any basemap used with a 3D scene, in local or global view, is the wrong resolution when I run ArcGIS Pro through remote desktop.

It looks as if the zoom level has been shifted a level or two:
[image]

compared to ArcGIS Pro running on my local machine:
[image]

Zooming and panning makes no difference, and every preset basemap in ArcGIS Pro has the same behavior.

I can't find any differences between my local machine and the machine that I remote into. They are both running ArcGIS Pro 1.2 alongside ArcGIS 10.2.1.

I'm fairly certain this wasn't occurring with ArcGIS Pro 1.1, but I am unable to locate an installer to verify.

Comment: I'd guess the cache is probably messed up. Can you try _PROJECT_ > _Options_ > _Display_ > click the Clear cache.

Comment: @KHibma Thanks for the tip, but it ended up being the Rendering Quality option. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up having nothing to do with the remote desktop connection, but with the display settings in ArcGIS Pro (Project -> Options -> Display).

On my desktop machine, the Rendering Quality was set to medium. My laptop was set to high. 
Setting the Rendering Quality back to 'High (quality)' causes the basemaps to be rendered as expected in a 3D scene.

Comment: At their core, basemaps are just raster datasets.  Lowering the rendering quality requests a lower resolution pyramid, which effectively asks for a lower LOD.  For basemaps that were authored for 2d, this means you could see vastly different content - as you saw.

Comment: @JeremyWright I now understand what's going on, but it's not exactly intuitive, especially since there's no indication that 'Rendering Quality' only pertains to 3D rendering.